# struggling with memory management in c++ and opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am struggling with memory management on a c++ project I have. ( just a fun project, to learn)
For now, it's basically a 3d file viewer built with glfw, opengl, glm and assimp. 
I am able to succesfully load some mesh files and display them in a window, with a shader, even display a texture ! whaou
I can even display multiple objects, which was not a simple as I though.

The "code base" is still pretty small, but large enough for me to make a lot of mistakes.

So basically it works as expected but for the fact that when loading a new mesh file, the program never really releases any memory;
it sometimes comes down 1 or 2 Mb, but apart from that the ram footprint keeps growing ( only when I load an object though, not continuously during program execution of course)

I have tried almost everything I can think of to manage the memory. But nothing I do has any effect.
I tried to limit a lot the use of "new" as I understand it's a little trickier to manage ( i.e need to manually delete )
I also tried everywhere I can to clear std::vectors when i don't need them anymore with the clear() function

I will put my main.cpp here
maybe the issue is in there.
All source files can be found at https://github.com/gui2one/angine

```
#include <iostream>
#include "application.h"
#include "pch.h"

#include "generators/gridmesh.h"
#include "generators/spheremesh.h"

Object* obj1 = new Object();

int nCols = 4;
Application app ;

Mesh loadNewObject(){
    char file[1024];
    FILE *f = popen("zenity --file-selection --title='choose a 3d file' ", "r");
    fgets(file, 1024, f);   
    std::cout << "Loading -> "<<file << "\n";           
    ObjLoader loader;
    Mesh mesh;
    std::string str(file);

    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n'), str.end());

    mesh = loader.assimp_load(str);

    return mesh;
}

void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    std::cout << "key ->" << key << ", scancode --> "<< scancode << "\n";
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_UP && action == GLFW_PRESS){

        nCols +=3;

        obj1->mesh.clearAll();

        SphereMesh* sphere = new SphereMesh();
        sphere->generate(obj1->mesh,20,nCols);

        delete sphere;

        std::cout << nCols << "\n";
        obj1->buildVbo();

    }else if (key == GLFW_KEY_DOWN && action == GLFW_PRESS){
        if( nCols > 4){
            nCols -=3;
            obj1->mesh.clearAll();

            SphereMesh* sphere = new SphereMesh();
            sphere->generate(obj1->mesh,20,nCols);

            delete sphere;
            std::cout << nCols << "\n";
            obj1->buildVbo();

        }
    }else if (key == 79 /* letter o*/ && action == GLFW_PRESS){

        nCols -=3;
        obj1->mesh.clearAll();
        obj1->mesh = loadNewObject();
        std::cout << nCols << "\n";
        obj1->buildVbo();
    }
}

int main(){



    std::cout << "angine PROJECT\n";

    //obj1->mesh = loadNewObject();

    SphereMesh* sphere = new SphereMesh();
    sphere->generate(obj1->mesh,20,nCols);        
    delete sphere;

    obj1->color->x = 0.9;
    obj1->color->y = 0.8;
    obj1->color->z = 0.5;
    obj1->color->w = 1.0;

    obj1->position->x = 1.2f;

    obj1->shader.loadVertexShaderSource("../src/res/shaders/basic_shader.vert");
    obj1->shader.loadFragmentShaderSource("../src/res/shaders/basic_shader.frag");  

    obj1->buildVbo();
    obj1->buildTexture();
    obj1->shader.createShader();


    app.objects.push_back(obj1);




    app.window.objects = app.objects;

    glfwSetKeyCallback(app.window.win, key_callback);
    while(!app.window.shouldClose()){



        app.window.refresh();
        obj1->rotation->x = glfwGetTime()*0.2;
        obj1->rotation->y = glfwGetTime()*0.13;
        obj1->rotation->z = glfwGetTime()*0.11;


    }

    return 0;
}
```

the class responsible for loading mesh data ObjLoader :

ObjLoader.h :

```
#ifndef OBJLOADER_H
#define OBJLOADER_H
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "../mesh.h"
#include "../vector3.h"

#include "../include/assimp/cimport.h"
#include "../include/assimp/scene.h"
#include "../include/assimp/postprocess.h"

class ObjLoader{
    public:
        Mesh assimp_load(std::string file_path);

};

#endif
```

ObjLoader.cpp :

```
Mesh ObjLoader::assimp_load(std::string file_path){

    const struct aiScene* scene = NULL;
    scene = aiImportFile(file_path.c_str(), aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_MaxQuality);

    if(scene){


        std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
        std::vector<float> positions;
        std::vector<float> normals;
        for (int i = 0; i < scene->mMeshes[0]->mNumFaces; i++)
        {
            Vertex vertex;

            for (int j = 0; j < scene->mMeshes[0]->mFaces[i].mNumIndices; j++)
            {
                    int index = scene->mMeshes[0]->mFaces[i].mIndices[j];

                    vertex.position.x = scene->mMeshes[0]->mVertices[index].x;
                    vertex.position.y = scene->mMeshes[0]->mVertices[index].y;
                    vertex.position.z = scene->mMeshes[0]->mVertices[index].z;

                    vertex.normal.x = scene->mMeshes[0]->mNormals[index].x;
                    vertex.normal.y = scene->mMeshes[0]->mNormals[index].y;
                    vertex.normal.z = scene->mMeshes[0]->mNormals[index].z;



                    if(scene->mMeshes[0]->HasTextureCoords(0)){

                        //~ std::cout << scene->mMeshes[0]->mTextureCoords[0][index].x  << "-------------"<< "\n";
                        vertex.t_coords.x = scene->mMeshes[0]->mTextureCoords[0][index].x;
                        vertex.t_coords.y = scene->mMeshes[0]->mTextureCoords[0][index].y;
                    }


                    vertices.push_back(vertex);

                    positions.push_back(scene->mMeshes[0]->mVertices[index].x);
                    positions.push_back(scene->mMeshes[0]->mVertices[index].y);
                    positions.push_back(scene->mMeshes[0]->mVertices[index].z);
            }

        }
        Mesh mesh;

        mesh.vertices = vertices;

        //// trying to delete everything I can
        delete scene;
        vertices.clear();
        positions.clear();
        normals.clear();

        return mesh;
    }else{
        Mesh empty_mesh;
        return empty_mesh;
    }


}
```

the fact is that issue remains even when not using this class to load a mesh, but generating the mesh procedurally.
I can't really post everything here, but I also have some opengl code to draw these meshes. Here I try also to "clear" everything and to unbind gl buffers after using them.

I'm out of ideas. 
I realize this question is pretty vague. i will try to make it more precise as I investigate more, but i really need some help to understand.

Comment: Why? `Object* obj1 = new Object();` No need to call new here.

Comment: This is not closed: `FILE *f = popen()`

Comment: If this code is running. i.e. it basically works. You can get a review at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Why? `SphereMesh* sphere = new SphereMesh();` Just do this: `SphereMesh sphere{};`

Comment: `the program never really releases any memory`. That;s pretty normal. Once an application get memory from the OS it never gives it back. It will manage that memory internally until it dies.

Comment: Stop doing: `typedef struct { /* STUFF*/ } StructName;` this is just C. Simply do: `struct StructName { /* STUFF*/ };` In C++ (unlike C) the structures are in the same name space as other identifiers (don't confuse with C++ namespace).

Comment: wouah thank you ,a lot of good infos here :)

Comment: so am I seeing an issue where there's none , memory wise ?

Comment: I don't think you have an issue based on this sample. I do think your code needs a review from an experienced C++ engineer. Your usage of new is very none typical (also bad as it leaves you vulnerable to leaks when there are exceptions). Looking at your project. I would pick a class get it reviewed. Apply the review to your whole code base yourself. Then get the next class reviewed. Repeat until the whole project is reviewed.

Comment: You can also have code review badges added to your README.md on the github repo. See: https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Looking at your code. Application/Object/Texture/Window all leak (destructor is not incorrect). None of them obey the rule of three or five. As a result your other classes that use them don't obey the rule of zero. Does not seem like you know about move semantics or RAII.

Comment: Alright ... I have a lot of work to do :) , I started removing some 'new' calls already. 
No I don't know anyting about the rules you're talking about. I will check this right away. 
Woua , C++ can be pretty overwhelming I would say, not easy to grasp, but I will slowly get there. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to tell just by reading your source without sitting there and stepping through a debugger looking at all of the dynamic memory allocation and deallocation of objects manually. This is a quite cumbersome task. It can be quite difficult to give a decisive answer. One thing I can do here is to provide you with some suggestions as I have built 3D graphics engines in the past.

You have already mentioned the fact of eliminating or minimizing the use of `new` and `delete` which is a very good start. What I'm about to propose is a design pattern and is mostly pseudo code of the structure. What you can do here is create a class that is responsible for all of the 3D Engines Assets that will manage your memory. This is not an easy task to achieve, but once you have the framework in place and working correctly it will help to make your code base and code management much easier.

You can create a class that will store all of your assets. However, to do so you will need common structures or classes for different objects. It may look something like this:

```
class AssetStorageManager {
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Texture>> textures_;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Font>>    fonts_;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Model>>   models_;
    std::vector<std::shard_ptr<GUI>>      guiObjects_; // Text Boxes, Buttons etc.
    // other possible containers: Music(BGM), SoundEffects etc.
    // shaders (Vertex, Fragment, Geometry & OpenGL Programs)...
public:
    AssetStorageManager() = default;
    ~AssetStorageManager() = default;

    void addTexture( const Texture& texture ) { /* ... ; */ }
    void removeTexture( unsigned int textureID ) { /* ... ; */ }
    void clearTextures() { /* remove all textures in container; */ }
    Texture* getTexture( unsigned int texureID );

    // basically the same 4 for all of your individual containers.
};
```

Sometimes a `vector` may not suffice, you may need a `map`, `unordered map`, `multimap`, `list`, `queue`(with priority), etc. It all depends on the need for which container you need.

This class will be responsible for managing memory. Another thing to consider is this; while the application is running you will only ever need a single instance of this class object, This is where a `Singleton` type object can be useful. If you make this class a `Singleton` object it would need to be created and initialized before you load any kind of objects from files to store them.

---

In my engine these are the types of singletons that I have, however, they inherit from a `Singleton` base class:

*-Singleton.h-*

```
namespace /* namespace name here*/ {

#ifndef SINGELTON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

class Singleton {
public:
    enum SingletonType {
        LOGGER = 0, // Must be first!
        SETTINGS,
        ENGINE,
        ANIMATION_MANAGER,
        SHADER_MANGER,
        ASSET_STORAGE,
        AUDIO_MANAGER,
        FONT_MANAGER,
        BATCH_MANAGER
    };
private:
    SingletonType type_;
public:
     virtual ~Singleton();
protected:
     explicit Singleton( SingletonType eType );

     void logMemoryAllocation( bool isAllocated ) const;
private:
     Singleton( const Singleton& c ); // not implemented
     Singleton& operator=( const Singleton& c ); // not implemented            
}; 

} // /*namespace name here */

#endif // SINGLETON_H
```

*-Singelton.cpp-*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Singleton.h"

#include "Logger.h"
#include "Settings.h"

namespace /* namespace name here*/ {

struct SingletonInfo {
    const std::string strSingletonName;
    bool              isConstructed;

    SingletonInfo( const std::string& strSingletonNameIn ) :
        strSingletonName( strSingletonNameIn ),
        isConstructed( false )
    {}
};

// Order Must Match Types Defined In Singleton::SingeltonType enum
static std::array<SingletonInfo, 9> s_aSingletons = { SingletonInfo( "Logger" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "Settings" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "Engine" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "AnimationManager" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "ShaderManager" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "AssetStorage" ),                                                  
                                                      SingletonInfo( "AudioManager" ), 
                                                      SingletonInfo( "FontManager" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "BatchManager" ) };

Singleton::Singleton( SingletonType eType ) :
m_eType( eType ) {
    bool bSaveInLog = s_aSingletons.at( TYPE_LOGGER ).isConstructed;

    try {
        if ( !s_aSingletons.at( eType ).isConstructed ) {
            // Test Initialization Order
            for ( int i = 0; i < eType; ++i ) {
                if ( !s_aSingletons.at( i ).isConstructed ) {
                    throw ExceptionHandler( s_aSingletons.at( i ).strSingletonName + " must be constructued before constructing " + s_aSingletons.at( eType ).strSingletonName, bSaveInLog );
                }
            }
            s_aSingletons.at( eType ).isConstructed = true;

            if ( s_aSingletons.at( TYPE_ENGINE ).isConstructed && 
                 Settings::get()->isDebugLoggingEnabled( Settings::DEBUG_MEMORY ) ) {
                logMemoryAllocation( true );
            }

        } else {
            throw ExceptionHandler( s_aSingletons.at( eType ).strSingletonName + " can only be constructed once.", bSaveInLog );
        }
    } catch ( std::exception& ) {
        // eType Is Out Of Range
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Invalid Singelton Type sepcified: " << eType;
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream, bSaveInLog );
    }
}    

Singleton::~Singleton() {
    if ( s_aSingletons.at( TYPE_ENGINE ).isConstructed &&
         Settings::get()->isDebugLoggingEnabled( Settings::DEBUG_MEMORY ) ) {
        logMemoryAllocation( false );
    }
    s_aSingletons.at( m_eType ).isConstructed = false;
}    

void Singleton::logMemoryAllocation( bool isAllocated ) const {
    if ( isAllocated ) {
        Logger::log( "Created " + s_aSingletons.at( m_eType ).strSingletonName );
    } else {
        Logger::log( "Destroyed " + s_aSingletons.at( m_eType ).strSingletonName );
    }
}

} // /*namespace name here */
```

This is the base class for all of my `Singleton` objects that manages different components of my engine. There are other classes involved such as a `Logger`, `Settings`, `BatchManager`, etc. all of which are `Singleton`s themselves that I won't show here. This will not compile on your machine.

My `AssetStorage` class that inherits from this looks as such:

*-AssetStorage.h*-

```
#ifndef ASSET_STORAGE_H
#define ASSET_STORAGE_H

#include "Singleton.h"
#include "CommonStructs.h"

namespace /*namespace name here*/ {

class BaseMko;
class GuiElement;
enum GuiType;

struct Texture {
    bool        hasAlphaChannel;
    bool        generateMipMap;
    bool        wrapRepeat;
    unsigned    uWidth;
    unsigned    uHeight;
    TextureInfo::FilterQuality filterQuality;
    std::vector<unsigned char> vPixelData;

    Texture( TextureInfo::FilterQuality filterQualityIn, bool generateMipMapIn, bool wrapRepeatIn ) :
        hasAlphaChannel( false ),
        generateMipMap( generateMipMapIn ),
        wrapRepeat( wrapRepeatIn ),
        uWidth( 0 ),
        uHeight( 0 ),
        filterQuality( filterQualityIn )
    {}
}; // Texture

class AssetStorage sealed : public Singleton {
private:
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseMko>>       MapMkoAssets;
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, TextureInfo>                    MapTextureInfos;
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<GuiElement>>    MapGuiAssets;

    MapMkoAssets    m_mkoAssets;
    MapTextureInfos m_textureInfos;
    MapGuiAssets    m_guiScreenAssets;
    MapGuiAssets    m_guiRenderableAssets;

    std::vector<std::string> m_vGuiForRemoval;

public:
    AssetStorage();
    virtual ~AssetStorage();

    static AssetStorage* const get();

    // Mko Objects
    BaseMko*    getMko( const std::string& strId ) const;
    void        add( BaseMko* pMko );
    bool        removeMko( const std::string& strId, bool removeTexture = false );
    void        showLoadedMkoObjects() const;

    // Texture Objects
    TextureInfo getTextureInfo( const std::string& strFilename ) const;
    TextureInfo add( const Texture& texture, const std::string& strFilename );
    bool        removeTextureInfo( const std::string& strFilename );
    bool        removeTextureInfo( unsigned uTextureId );
    void        showLoadedTextureInfo() const;

    // Gui Objects
    GuiElement* getGuiElement( const std::string& strId, GuiType type ) const;
    void        add( GuiElement* pGui, GuiType type );
    bool        removeGuiElement( const std::string& strId, bool removeTextures = false );
    template<typename T>
    bool        removeGuiElement( T* pGui, bool removeTextures = false );
    void        markGuiForRemoval( const std::string& strId );
    void        cleanOrphanedGuiObjects();
    void        showLoadedGuiObjects() const;

private:
    AssetStorage( const AssetStorage& c ) = delete; // Not Implemented
    AssetStorage& operator=( const AssetStorage& c ) = delete; // Not Implemented

    // Gui Objects
    GuiElement* getGuiElement( const std::string& strId, const MapGuiAssets& guiMap ) const;
    void        add( GuiElement* pGui, MapGuiAssets& guiMap );
    bool        removeGuiElement( const std::string& strId, MapGuiAssets& guiMap, bool removeTextures );
}; // AssetStorage

template<typename T>
inline bool AssetStorage::removeGuiElement( T * pGui, bool removeTextures ) {
    return false;
}

} // /*namespace name here*/

#endif // ASSET_STORAGE_H
```

*-AssetStorage.cpp-*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AssetStorage.h"

#include "BaseMko.h"
#include "BlockThread.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "Settings.h"
#include "GuiScreen.h"
#include "GuiRenderable.h"

namespace /*namespace name here*/ {

// Core OpenGL API Found In Opengl32.lib
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif
GLAPI void APIENTRY glBindTexture( GLenum target, GLuint texture );
GLAPI void APIENTRY glDeleteTextures( GLsizei n, const GLuint *textures );
GLAPI void APIENTRY glGenTextures( GLsizei n, GLuint *textures );
GLAPI void APIENTRY glTexImage2D( GLenum target, GLint level, GLint internalformat, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLint border, GLenum format, GLenum type, const GLvoid *pixels );
GLAPI void APIENTRY glTexParameteri( GLenum target, GLenum pname, GLint param );
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif

// OpenGl Texture API
static PFNGLGENERATEMIPMAPPROC glGenerateMipmap = nullptr;

static Settings*        s_pSettings     = nullptr;
static AssetStorage*    s_pAssetStorage = nullptr;

static CRITICAL_SECTION s_criticalSection;

static void defineOpenglApi() {
    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Can not initialize function pointer named: ";
    std::string strApiName;

    if ( Settings::get()->getOpenglVersion().x >= 3 ) {
        strApiName = "glGenerateMipmap";
        if ( ( glGenerateMipmap = (PFNGLGENERATEMIPMAPPROC)wglGetProcAddress( strApiName.c_str() ) ) == nullptr ) {
            strStream << strApiName;
            throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
        }
    }

}    

AssetStorage::AssetStorage() :
Singleton( TYPE_ASSET_STORAGE ) {
    InitializeCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );    
    defineOpenglApi();    
    s_pSettings = Settings::get();
    s_pAssetStorage = this;
}

AssetStorage::~AssetStorage() {
    s_pAssetStorage = nullptr;

    m_mkoAssets.clear();
    m_guiRenderableAssets.clear();
    m_guiScreenAssets.clear();

    for( MapTextureInfos::iterator itTexture = m_textureInfos.begin(); itTexture != m_textureInfos.end(); ++itTexture ) {
        if ( s_pSettings->isDebugLoggingEnabled( Settings::DEBUG_MEMORY ) ) {
            Logger::log( std::string( "Destroyed " ) + itTexture->first );
        }
        glDeleteTextures( 1, &(itTexture->second.uTextureId ) );
    }
    m_textureInfos.clear();

    DeleteCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );
}    

AssetStorage* const AssetStorage::get() {
    if ( nullptr == s_pAssetStorage ) {
        throw ExceptionHandler( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " failed, AssetStorage has not been constructed yet" ) );
    }
    return s_pAssetStorage;
} 

BaseMko* AssetStorage::getMko( const std::string& strId ) const {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );

    MapMkoAssets::const_iterator itMkoAssets = m_mkoAssets.find( strId );
    if ( itMkoAssets == m_mkoAssets.cend() ) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    return itMkoAssets->second.get();
}

void AssetStorage::add( BaseMko* pMko ) {
    if ( nullptr == pMko ) {
        throw ExceptionHandler( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " pMko==nullptr passed in" ) );
    }
    if ( nullptr != getMko( pMko->getId() ) ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " attempting to store " << pMko->getId() << " multiple times";
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
    }

    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );
    m_mkoAssets.insert( MapMkoAssets::value_type( pMko->getId(), std::shared_ptr<BaseMko>( pMko ) ) );
}    

bool AssetStorage::removeMko( const std::string& strId, bool removeTexture ) {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );
    MapMkoAssets::iterator itMkoAsset = m_mkoAssets.find( strId );
    if ( itMkoAsset == m_mkoAssets.end() ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " failed. " << strId << " was not found in Asset Storage";
        Logger::log( strStream );
        return false;
    }

    if ( removeTexture ) {
        itMkoAsset->second->clearTextureInfos();        
    }
    m_mkoAssets.erase( itMkoAsset );

    return true;
}     

void AssetStorage::showLoadedMkoObjects() const {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );
    if ( m_mkoAssets.size() > 0 ) {
        Logger::log( "Loaded mko objects listed below: ", Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
        for each( const std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseMko>>& mko in m_mkoAssets ) {
            std::ostringstream strStream;
            strStream << "mkoId(" << mko.first << ") ";
            Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
        }
    } else {
        Logger::log( "There are no loaded mko objects.", Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
    }
    Logger::log( " ", Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
}

TextureInfo AssetStorage::getTextureInfo( const std::string& strFilename ) const {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );
    MapTextureInfos::const_iterator itTexture = m_textureInfos.find( strFilename );
    if ( itTexture == m_textureInfos.cend() ) {
        return TextureInfo();
    }
    return itTexture->second;
}

// This Can Only Be Called From The Main OpenGL Thread
TextureInfo AssetStorage::add( const Texture& texture, const std::string& strFilename ) {
    if ( INVALID_UNSIGNED != getTextureInfo( strFilename ).uTextureId ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " can not store " << strFilename << " multiple times";
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
    }

    TextureInfo textureInfo;
    textureInfo.hasTransparency = texture.hasAlphaChannel;
    textureInfo.size = glm::uvec2( texture.uWidth, texture.uHeight );

    glGetError(); // Clear Errors

    glGenTextures( 1, &textureInfo.uTextureId );

    GLenum err = glGetError();
    if ( err != GL_NO_ERROR ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " failed glGenTextures with error code 0x" << std::hex << err;
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
    }

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureInfo.uTextureId );

    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, ( texture.wrapRepeat ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE ) );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, ( texture.wrapRepeat ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE ) );

    const glm::uvec2& openglVersion = s_pSettings->getOpenglVersion();

    if ( texture.generateMipMap ) {
        switch ( texture.filterQuality ) {
            case TextureInfo::FILTER_NONE : {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
                break;
            }
            case TextureInfo::FILTER_GOOD: {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
                break;
            }
            case TextureInfo::FILTER_BEST: {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
            }
        } // Switch

        if ( openglVersion.x < 3 ) {
            // In OpenGL v3 GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP Is Deprecated, And In 3.1+ It Was Removed
            // So For Those Versions We Use glGenerateMipmap below
            static const unsigned int GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP = 0x8191;
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE );
        }
    } else { // No MipMaps
        switch( texture.filterQuality ) {
            case TextureInfo::FILTER_NONE:
            case TextureInfo::FILTER_GOOD: {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
            }
        } 
    }

    // Load Texture Into Video Memory
    glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, texture.hasAlphaChannel ? 4 : 1 );
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        ( texture.hasAlphaChannel ? GL_RGBA8 : GL_RGB8 ),
        texture.uWidth,
        texture.uHeight,
        0,
        ( texture.hasAlphaChannel ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB ),
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        &texture.vPixelData[0] );

    if ( texture.generateMipMap && openglVersion.x >= 3 ) {
        glGenerateMipmap( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    }

    // Store TextureId
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );
    m_textureInfos.insert( MapTextureInfos::value_type( strFilename, textureInfo ) );

    if ( s_pSettings->isDebugLoggingEnabled( Settings::DEBUG_MEMORY ) ) {
        Logger::log( std::string( "Created " ) + strFilename );
    }

    return textureInfo;
}    

bool AssetStorage::removeTextureInfo( const std::string& strFilename ) {
    MapTextureInfos::iterator itTexture = m_textureInfos.find( strFilename );
    if ( itTexture == m_textureInfos.end() ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " failed. " << strFilename << " was not found in Asset Storage";
        Logger::log( strStream );

        return false;
    }

    if ( s_pSettings->isDebugLoggingEnabled( Settings::DEBUG_MEMORY ) ) {
        Logger::log( std::string( "Destroyed " ) + strFilename );
    }

    glDeleteTextures( 1, &(itTexture->second.uTextureId) );
    m_textureInfos.erase( itTexture );

    return true;
}     

bool AssetStorage::removeTextureInfo( unsigned uTextureId ) {
    for ( MapTextureInfos::iterator itTexture = m_textureInfos.begin(); itTexture != m_textureInfos.end(); ++itTexture ) {
        if ( uTextureId == itTexture->second.uTextureId ) {
            if ( s_pSettings->isDebugLoggingEnabled( Settings::DEBUG_MEMORY ) ) {
                Logger::log( std::string( "Destroyed " ) + itTexture->first );
            }

            glDeleteTextures( 1, &uTextureId );
            m_textureInfos.erase( itTexture );

            return true;
        }
    }

    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " failed. TextureId[" << uTextureId << "] was not found in AssetStorage";
    Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_WARNING );

    return false;
}     

void AssetStorage::showLoadedTextureInfo() const {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );
    Logger::log( "Loaded textures listed below: ", Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
    for each ( const std::pair<std::string, TextureInfo>& texture in m_textureInfos ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << "textureId(" << texture.second.uTextureId << ") "
            << "transparency(" << ( texture.second.hasTransparency ? "Y" : "N" ) << ") "
            << "size" << texture.second.size << " "
            << texture.first << std::endl;
        Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
    }
    Logger::log( " ", Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
}     

GuiElement* AssetStorage::getGuiElement( const std::string& strId, GuiType type ) const {
    switch( type ) {
        case GUI_SCREEN: {
            return getGuiElement( strId, m_guiScreenAssets );
        }
        case GUI_RENDERABLE: {
            return getGuiElement( strId, m_guiRenderableAssets );   
        }
        default : {
            std::ostringstream strStream;
            strStream << __FUNCTION__ << "Unrecognzied guiType = " << type;
            throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
        }
    }
    return nullptr; 

}     

GuiElement* AssetStorage::getGuiElement( const std::string& strId, const MapGuiAssets& guiMap ) const {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );
    MapGuiAssets::const_iterator itGuiAsset = guiMap.find( strId );
    if ( itGuiAsset == guiMap.cend() ) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    return itGuiAsset->second.get();
}

void AssetStorage::add( GuiElement* pGui, GuiType type ) {
    if ( nullptr == pGui ) {
        throw ExceptionHandler( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " pGui==nullptr passed in" ) );
    }

    // Make Sure Name Is Unique Across All GuiElement Types
    for ( int i = 0; i < GUI_UKNOWN; ++i ) {
        if ( getGuiElement( pGui->getId(), (GuiType)i ) != nullptr ) {
            std::ostringstream strStream;
            strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " attempting to store " << pGui->getId() << " multiple times";
            throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
        }
    }

    switch( type ) {
        case GUI_SCREEN: {
            add( pGui, m_guiScreenAssets );
            break;
        }
        case GUI_RENDERABLE: {
            add( pGui, m_guiRenderableAssets );
            break;
        }
        default: {
            std::ostringstream strStream;
            strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " unrecognized GuiType = " << type;
        }
    }
}     

void AssetStorage::add( GuiElement* pGui, MapGuiAssets& guiMap ) {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );
    guiMap.insert( MapGuiAssets::value_type( pGui->getId(), std::shared_ptr<GuiElement>( pGui ) ) );
}

template<>
bool AssetStorage::removeGuiElement( GuiScreen* pGui, bool removeTextures ) {
    return removeGuiElement( pGui->getId(), m_guiScreenAssets, removeTextures );
}     

template<>
bool AssetStorage::removeGuiElement( GuiRenderable* pGui, bool removeTextures ) {
    return removeGuiElement( pGui->getId(), m_guiRenderableAssets, removeTextures );
}     

bool AssetStorage::removeGuiElement( const std::string& strId, bool removeTextures ) {
    // Find Which Type This Gui Element Is In
    for ( int i = 0; i < GUI_UKNOWN; ++i ) {
        GuiElement* pGui = getGuiElement( strId, (GuiType)i );
        if ( pGui != nullptr ) {
            // Found It
            switch( static_cast<GuiType>( i ) ) {
                case GUI_SCREEN: {
                    return removeGuiElement( pGui->getId(), m_guiScreenAssets, removeTextures );
                }
                case GUI_RENDERABLE: {
                    return removeGuiElement( pGui->getId(), m_guiRenderableAssets, removeTextures );
                }
                default: {
                    std::ostringstream strStream;
                    strStream << __FUNCTION__  << " unrecognized GuiType = " << i;
                    throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " failed. " << strId << " was not found in AssetStorage";
    Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_WARNING );
    return false;
}     

bool AssetStorage::removeGuiElement( const std::string& strId, MapGuiAssets& guiMap, bool removeTextures ) {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );
    MapGuiAssets::iterator itGuiAsset = guiMap.find( strId );
    if ( itGuiAsset == guiMap.end() ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " failed. " << strId << " was not found in AssetStorage";
        Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_WARNING );
        return false;

    } else {
        itGuiAsset->second.get()->setRemoveTextures( removeTextures );
        guiMap.erase( itGuiAsset );

        // When The Above Gui Was Deleted, There Might Have Been Some Children
        // That Also Got Marked For Removal. We Can Remove Them Now Here
        for ( unsigned i = 0; i < m_vGuiForRemoval.size(); ++i ) {
            itGuiAsset = m_guiRenderableAssets.find( m_vGuiForRemoval[i] );
            if ( itGuiAsset != m_guiRenderableAssets.end() ) {
                // Remove This Gui
                itGuiAsset->second.get()->setRemoveTextures( false );
                m_guiRenderableAssets.erase( itGuiAsset );

            } else {
                std::ostringstream strStream;
                strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " failed to find " << m_vGuiForRemoval[i] << " for removal from the m_guiRenderableAssets";
                Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_WARNING );
            }
        }
        m_vGuiForRemoval.clear();

        return true;    
    }
}     

void AssetStorage::markGuiForRemoval( const std::string& strId ) {
    m_vGuiForRemoval.push_back( strId );
}     

void AssetStorage::cleanOrphanedGuiObjects() {
} 

void AssetStorage::showLoadedGuiObjects() const {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );

    // Reset Print Flags
    for each( const std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<GuiElement>>& gui in m_guiRenderableAssets ) {
        GuiRenderable* pGui = dynamic_cast<GuiRenderable*>( gui.second.get() );
        if ( pGui != nullptr ) {
             pGui->resetPrinted();
        }
    }

    if ( m_guiScreenAssets.size() > 0 ) {
        Logger::log( "Loaded gui screen's: ", Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
        for each ( const std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<GuiElement>>& gui in m_guiScreenAssets ) {
            gui.second.get()->print();
            Logger::log( " ", Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
        }
    } else {
        Logger::log( "There are no loaded gui screens.", Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
    }
    Logger::log( " ", Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );

    bool isMessageShown = false;
    for each( const std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<GuiElement>>& gui in m_guiRenderableAssets ) {
        GuiRenderable* pGui = dynamic_cast<GuiRenderable*>( gui.second.get() );
        if ( !pGui->wasPrinted() ) {
            if ( !isMessageShown ) {
                 isMessageShown = true;
                 Logger::log( "Loaded gui renderables not attached to a screen: ", Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
            }
            pGui->print();
        }
    }
    if ( isMessageShown ) {
        Logger::log( " ", Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
    }
} 

} // /*namespace name here*/
```

This was originally built in Visual Studio 2010 & 12 and has been ported over to VS 2015 so this doesn't utilize all of `modern c++` techniques but does use many features from `C++11`. Hopefully one day I will port this over to `2017` version to utilize `C++17`.

---

I had initially proposed to have all of your stored objects into a single class, however with any kind of 3D Engine the memory class will explode in size very quickly as you can see from the `AssetStorage` class above, so to help keep things simple and more modular, I have broken them down into individual Managing classes.

Comment: Hi, I’m afraid it’s a little too complicated for me. Too many concepts I don’t yet have a grasp on. l wouldn’t know where to begin.

Comment: @gui2one Yeah it does take time and effort to learn them, and when you think you have a handle on it and you think you know all you need to know; you will realize just how much of a beginner you are.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was the issue in my code.
I was loading data inside a persistent object with some

```
glGenBuffers()
```

but I was never using any

```
glDeleteBuffers(1,&m_id)
```

I imagine that every time I called glGenBuffers(1,&m_id); opengl creates a totally new buffer, so I have to clear the one before.

My program is now consumming a normal amount of memory.